# How to programmatically determine process running x11 window in Java

Tags: java, linux, x11, jna

I understand this might not be possible, but if it is, any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to, in java, gather the size, position, window ID, window title, and program of every visible x11 window open in linux. While I can do all of this using runProcess along with xprop, xwininfo, etc, I'd prefer to do so without the use of external programs.

Using JNA, I've been able to gather everything other than the program name. Is it possible to get the PID, as one would with xprop, entirely with Java? Ideally, I'd want to be able to get the same general info as I'd be getting with xprop [id] _NET_WM_PID.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I want to populate a list of all of the open windows, and allow the user to select one and create a transparent overlay on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GraphicsEnvironment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html).

Its `isHeadless()` means there is no GUI.

Also for connected screen devices here is the starting point.

The PIDs are now available, either in java 9 or already 8.

Comment: I'm seeing ways to get graphics devices here, but other than being able to get any full-screen windows on a given graphics device, I don't see any means of getting windows or PIDs. Am I missing something?

Comment: GraphicsEnvironment has some goodies I wanted to mention. PIDs are a long awaited addition to java processes to be able to get now. I did not look into that. Could maybe squeezed into a comment. Top-level windows can be gotten by java.awt too (`Window.getWindows()`).

Comment: awt's getWindows function wouldn't help me in this case. I'm trying to get info on all of the windows _not_ created by the java application.